# Using a Verbatim inside bclogo in a new environment definition

Tags: environments, verbatim, bclogo

I would like to create a new environment to provide some LaTeX code (or from other languages)

So far, I tried the following code

```
\usepackage{bclogo}
\newenvironment{code}
{   \begin{bclogo}
        [couleur = black!10, couleurBord = black!50,
        arrondi = 0.1, logo = \bccrayon]
        {Code \LaTeX :}

        \bigskip

        \begin{verbatim}
}
{       \end{verbatim}
    \end{bclogo}
}
```

But, this creates an error during the compilation...

> ! File ended while scanning use of \next.  \par <*> essai3.tex
>
> I suspect you have forgotten a '}', causing me to read past where you wanted me to stop. I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious, you'd better type `E' or`X' now and fix your file.
>
> ! Emergency stop. <*> essai3.tex
>
> *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
>
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>
> ...
>
> ! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

If someone have an idea to get through this error, I would sincerely say "Thank you very much, Master"

Comment: Please have a look on `tcolorbox` and its `tcblisting` feature which provides nice boxes too combined with listings.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Nesting `verbatim` inside macros is not possible, but it is possible inside `environments` using the starter and 'end' - commands of the `verbatim` environment, i.e. `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim`.

At the end of my code answer I provide also a way with `tcolorbox` showing LaTeX code and its compilation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\newenvironment{code}
{%   
  \bclogo[couleur = black!10, couleurBord = black!50,
  arrondi = 0.1, logo = \bccrayon]
  {Code \LaTeX :}
  \bigskip
  \verbatim
}
{ 
  \endverbatim
  \endbclogo
}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing only}

\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
\end{code}

And a \verb!tcolorbox! version:

\begin{tcblisting}{colback={white!40!yellow}}
\LaTeXe\ is nice!
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much for your rapid answer!!
I had tried it before, and I still have the same error...

I'm working with TexMaker on Mac Os X, and the coloration begins to be all red after my old "\begin{verbatim}" or the new "\verbatim", till the end of the file.

Any idea?

Comment: @MathTolliob: No, I haven't. I have shown you that it works on Linux and TL 2016, `TeXMaker` is an 'editor' only -- I don't use such 'editors'

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\newenvironment{code}
{\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{bclogo}[couleur = black!10, couleurBord = black!50,
  arrondi = 0.1, logo = \bccrayon]
  {Code \LaTeX :}\par\nobreak\bigskip
  \begin{Verbatim}}
{\end{Verbatim}\end{bclogo}}

\begin{document}
\begin{code}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
\end{code}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "Thank you very much, Master"!!!!
That's perfect!