# How to make a new environment be verbatim inside \scalebox with listings package?

Tags: errors, verbatim, text-manipulation, technical-environment, scalebox

After [@JPi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43843) answer on [How to use \scalebox around my environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387515/how-to-use-scalebox-around-my-environment) and comment pointing to the question [Verbatim in environ’s \BODY](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51239/verbatim-in-environ-s-body) I tried:

1. Writing the contents to a file
2. Print it on verbatim mode, wrapping `scalebox` around it with `\input`

However looking over this logic, seems impossible to wrap the verbatim contents around the way I am trying to. Perhaps I missed something on the explanation at the question [Verbatim in environ’s \BODY](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51239/verbatim-in-environ-s-body)?

Thinking better, mixing the `verbatim` and `listings` packages looks pretty redundant. So we could just remove the `verbatim` usage from this and use solely the `listings` as it already does verbatim output.

Now the question would became, does `listings` can be put inside `scalebox`?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
    % Verbatim in environ’s \BODY
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51239/verbatim-in-environ-s-body
    \RequirePackage{listings}
    \lst@RequireAspects{writefile}

    \lstnewenvironment{myenvironment}
    {
        % Write file to given filename
        \lst@BeginWriteFile{\jobname.mul}
    }
    {
        % closes output file
        \lst@EndWriteFile
        \scalebox{.2}
        {
            % Uncommenting this, throws the errors
            % \begin{verbatim}
            \input{\jobname.mul}
            % \end{verbatim}
        }
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    This is normal text.

    \begin{myenvironment}
         How to make this environment be {\bfseries verbatim}?
    \end{myenvironment}

    \scalebox{.2}{This is a scale box example.}

    \begin{verbatim}
         This is a verbatim example.
    \end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But if I uncomment the verbatim environment arount `\input{\jobname.mul}` all kinds of errors are throw.

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.213     \end{myenvironment}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.213     \end{myenvironment}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.213     \end{myenvironment}

Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.213     \end{myenvironment}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.213     \end{myenvironment}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.213     \end{myenvironment}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.213     \end{myenvironment}

I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+cmtt on input line 213.

(D:\User\Documents\latex\texmfs\install\tex\latex\base\t1cmtt.fd
File: t1cmtt.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
! Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.213     \end{myenvironment}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
\input {\jobname .mul} \end {verbatim} 
! Paragraph ended before \verbatim@ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.213     \end{myenvironment}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<recently read> }

l.213     \end{myenvironment}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\Gscale@box ...cale@y {#2}\setbox \z@ \hbox {{#3}}
                                                  \setbox \tw@ \hbox {\Gscal...
l.213     \end{myenvironment}

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

Related:

1. [Using a Verbatim inside bclogo in a new environment definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325394/using-a-verbatim-inside-bclogo-in-a-new-environment-definition)
2. [How to make a new environment behave like an existing environment? (Part 2: endnotes and comments)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/143100/how-to-make-a-new-environment-behave-like-an-existing-environment-part-2-endn)
3. [Defining a new environment extending a verbatim environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114643/defining-a-new-environment-extending-a-verbatim-environment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store verbatim material you need an lrbox:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,graphicx}

\newsavebox{\mylistingbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\mylistingbox}
\begin{lstlisting}
\section \textbf & %
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

Some text \scalebox{0.5}{\usebox{\mylistingbox}}

\end{document}
```

[image]